# How to decrypt a file encrypted on different openssl version and different os?

Tags: openssl

I encrypt a file on server A.

```
uname -a
Linux hwy 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017

key="xxxxxxxx"
openssl enc -des3 -a -salt -in /tmp/wp.sql -k ${key} -out /tmp/wp.sql.asc
```

To push the file to server B, and decrypt it on sever B.

```
uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 2.6.32-042stab132.1 #1 SMP Wed Jul 11 13:51:30 MSK 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

To decrypt it on server B.

```
key="xxxxxxxx"
openssl enc -d -des3 -a -salt -k ${key} -in /tmp/wp.sql.asc -out /tmp/wp.sql
```

It encounter  error info:

```
bad decrypt
139640119146384:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:evp_enc.c:592:
```

How can i decrypt the file on my server B?
Should i upgrade openssl's version  on server B from `1.0.2k-fips` to  `1.1.0f` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default hash used in 1.1 is SHA256 where as 1.0 uses MD5. Try using the flag -md sha256 with your decrypt command